# function in dax to force indirect relationship?

Tags: dax

I have the below model:
[image]

[image]

When I want to display revenue by segment, it just gives me the totals:
[image]

(The above is wrong; it should roughly be half for A and half for B, but it just displays totals 3 times...)

Is there a function in DAX to enforce this segmentation?? (the segmentation comes from **ClientType**, which is not directly related, but through **Client**.

Comment: Check your model; Currently you get Revenue by Date table (check from -> to and filters direction); Disable ClientType - Date relationship; modify Client - ClientType relationship then check one more time

Comment: But I need to pick the ClientType based on the Date[Year] selected on the filter. So, I  can't Disable ClientType - Date relationship.

Comment: think over the design of the model. The ideal model should have a star / snowflake structure. If this is not possible, then try: a) add something from Client to your visualization to force this road of relationship (also change relationship filters directions);
b) You can try to disable relationship Date - ClientType and add some statement in your measure  x = calculate(sum(x), FILTER(all(ClientType[FY]), ClientType[FY] = selectedvalue(Date[Year])))